# Table Aliases into Subqueries

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

*(Submitting here to assist other Snowflake Users who may run into similar challenges... Interested to see if there are any additional recommendations beyond what's bee provided already.)*

Why doesn't table alias work into subqueries?

I was using a sample table select query but it doesn't work when I coded a table alias.

```
select * from SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCDS_SF100TCL.STORE as t
where 
t.S_REC_START_DATE = (
          select max(i.S_REC_START_DATE) from t as i
              where i.S_REC_START_DATE < '2000-01-01'
        )
```

I got a SQL compilation error: `Object 'T' does not exist`.

is not possible to use table alias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Previously provided by Mike Walton, a tenured member of Snowflake's Professional Services team)*

You can, but not that way. You should use a CTE, instead:

```
WITH t as (
  select * from SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCDS_SF100TCL.STORE
)
select * FROM t
where t.S_REC_START_DATE = (
         select max(S_REC_START_DATE) as S_REC_START_DATE from t
              where S_REC_START_DATE < '2000-01-01'
        )
```

***Any other ideas and/or recommendations?***

Comment: Client believes this is a solid solution... looking to see if there are additional ways to "solve for X"...